# Devise login custom endpoint, current_user session id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, devise

I have a mobile application that needs to login to a legacy Rails 3.2 app.

I have an endpoint that the mobile app makes a POST request to passing the username and password.

I want to verify the password and sign in the user and then need to save the now signed user's session id.

I have tried the following:

```
user = User.find_by_username(params[:username])
if user.valid_password?(params[:password])
  sign_in(:user, user)
  session_id = request.session_options[:id]
  p "session id: #{session_id}"
  current_user.logins.create({ session_id: session_id })
end
```

When I check my redis store that session id being stored is different from the session_id I print out. I read somewhere that this is because rails creates a session id for the request and then once you sign in you get a new session id to prevent fake requests. How can I get the signed in user's session_id?